# Springboot Micro-service concurrent call filter

Tags: spring-boot, microservices

I have a Springboot controller 'verify' (E.g. http://localhost/verify) exposed as PUT where user will provide an ID in request body.
In my service, I retrieve this ID and call an external service (e.g. http://external-service/verify/ID).
Constraint here is that the call should be sent to external service only once per ID (i.e. external service should not be called twice with same ID).

Can someone please help me here as I get multiple verify request on my service and I want to ensure that only first call gets to call external service?

Comment: Add a flag in db level, once your service successfully hit external service successfully then flip that flap and persist in db.
you also need to make that piece of code in a synchronized block and make sure flag is ture then call external service else avoid that call.

Comment: What you’re trying is to create state in stateless REST, so your options are(assuming you have multiple instances) 1) distributed cache or 2) database as mentioned above. If you’re sure there’ll ever be only one instance, you can go with in memory cache